# R dplyr filter based on matching search term with first words of any work in select columns

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I'm trying to filter words from selected columns based on keywords that start the words in the text of match a particular regular expression. Here, I'm trying to pick all words starting with "bio" or "15". But the search terms can also be found in the middle of some words like symbiotic for the Name column and 161540 for the Code column.

```
**Name**                     **Code**
Biofuel is good          159403
Bioecological is good    161540
Probiotics is good       159883
Good is symbiotic        1877447
```

I tried the code below

```
Innov_filter <- Innov_Data %>% 
  select(everything()) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(str_to_lower(Name), "bio") | str_detect(str_to_lower(Code), "bio"))
```

This is however not working because it is filtering the last row which doesn't fit into any of the conditions. I will appreciate help in strict search based on the first appearance of the search term as part of the word and not just in any location of the word.

Thanks

Comment: try "^bio" to indicate you want to only look at the beginning

Comment: So you want to filter rows where `Name` has "Bio" in it in the first word and `Code` starts with 15 ?

Comment: @RonakShah Yes. that is what I want to do

Comment: Bio in the first word of the first column, or in the first column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

If we want to select any word which starts with "bio" we can do

```
df %>%
  filter(str_detect(str_to_lower(Name), "\\bbio") | str_detect(Code, "^15"))
```

OR the same thing in base R

```
df[sapply(strsplit(df$Name, "\\s+"), function(x) any(grepl("^bio", tolower(x)))) | 
                                                 grepl("^15", df$Code), ]
```

---

**Original Answer**

This selects rows where "bio" is present in first word of `Name` (`word(Name)` returns only first word) or `Code` which starts with "15".

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  filter(str_detect(str_to_lower(word(Name)), "bio") | str_detect(Code, "^15"))


#                   Name   Code
#1       Biofuel is good 159403
#2 Bioecological is good 161540
#3    Probiotics is good 159883
```

---

Using the same logic but in base R, we can do

```
df[sapply(strsplit(df$Name, "\\s+"), function(x) grepl("bio", tolower(x[1]))) 
                                  | grepl("^15", df$Code), ]

#                   Name   Code
#1       Biofuel is good 159403
#2 Bioecological is good 161540
#3    Probiotics is good 159883
```

Here, it splits the string at empty space and then extracts the first word from each (`x[1]`) and check if it has "bio" in it OR get rows which starts with "15".

Comment: I just realised this will only pick words at the beginning of the sentence. Do you know how I can pick any word in any position of the sentence as long as it starts with Bio? e.g this is good biofuel –

Comment: @BayuoBlaise Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `filter_all` with `any_vars`

```
df %>% 
   filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(str_to_lower(.), "^(bio|15)")))
#                  Name   Code
#1       Biofuel is good 159403
#2 Bioecological is good 161540
#3    Probiotics is good 159883
```

NOTE: If it is a subset of columns that needs the conditions to apply, use `filter_at`

If we need to pick any word that start with 'Bio' in a sentence, wrap with word boundary (`\\b`)

```
df %>% 
   filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(str_to_lower(.), "\\bbio|^15")))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Name = structure(c(2L, 1L, 4L, 3L), 
   .Label = c("Bioecological is good", 
"Biofuel is good", "Good is symbiotic", "Probiotics is good"), 
  class = "factor"), 
Code = c(159403, 161540, 159883, 1877447)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

To filter "bio" at the beginning of lines you can use [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) using for example function `grepl()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(Name = c("Biofuel is good",
                         "Bioecological is good",
                         "Probiotics is good",
                         "Good is symbiotic"),
                Code = c(159403, 161540, 159883, 1877447))
df %>%
    filter(grepl("^bio", tolower(Name)))
#>                    Name   Code
#> 1       Biofuel is good 159403
#> 2 Bioecological is good 161540
```

The `^` in `grepl()` first argument `^bio` indicates that the match string have to begin with the letters "bio".
Using package `stringr` that would become:

```
df %>%
    filter(str_detect(tolower(Name), "^bio"))
#>                    Name   Code
#> 1       Biofuel is good 159403
#> 2 Bioecological is good 161540
```

By the way the use of `select(everything())` in your workflow is optional as by default `dplyr` keeps all columns and apply the `filter()` function considering all columns.

Comment: Thank you for the further explanations of the grepl () function.

Comment: I just realised this will only pick words at the beginning of the sentence. Do you know how I can pick any word in any position of the sentence as long as it starts with Bio? e.g this is good biofuel

Comment: So in this case you can use the special char `\b` which is a word boundary in **reg**ular **ex**pressions (regex). So the code would be `filter(grepl("\\bbio", tolower(Name)))`. You have to use `\\b` to escape the backslash otherwise it is recognized as a regular backslash character.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this, bio in the first word, 15 in Code:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(str_detect(tolower(Name), "^bio") | str_detect(tolower(Code), "15")) 

                   Name   Code
1       Biofuel is good 159403
2 Bioecological is good 161540
3    Probiotics is good 159883
```

With renamed data:

```
df <-read.table(text = "Name                     Code
  'Biofuel is good'          159403
                'Bioecological is good'    161540
                'Probiotics is good'       159883
                'Good is symbiotic'        1877447", header = T)
```