# How to filter out a particular phrase from a unstructured data set in R and put it in a new data frame

Tags: r, filtering

I am working on cleaning up a large unstructured data actually a code page. I need to extract a particular phrase all starting with <bi:component name= from this code and put it in a new data frame in a column.

Here is my sample data in .txt file. I need to look for the term <bi:component name and whatever appears after type= should be put in a new column called component.

```
</bi:data_source_alias>
    <bi:component name="ROOT" type="ABSOLUTE_LAYOUT_COMPONENT">
        <bi:component name="CHART_1" type="com_sap_ip_bi_VizFrame">
            <bi:property name="LEFT_MARGIN" value="31"/>`       <bi:property name="TOP_MARGIN" value="64"/>
<bi:component name="SCORECARD_1" type="com_sap_ip_bi_Scorecard">
            <bi:property name="LEFT_MARGIN" value="9"/>
```

This is what I've done so far.

1. Read the entire .txt file into a data frame called df1
2. Then I've applied filter on df1 using the following commands

   ```
   comp_type <- df1 %>%
       filter(str_detect(str_to_lower(Value), "\\<bi:component name="))

   comp_type <- df1[sapply(strsplit(df1$Value, "\\s+"), 
      function(x) any(grepl("^<bi:component name=", tolower((x))))) ]
   ```

Value is the field name where the list of all the components appears. [Image showing data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drvpX.jpg)

But I am getting an error with the above command.

> Error in UseMethod("filter_") : no applicable method for 'filter_'
> applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'logical')"

I've referred to the below link for help and referred to few other sites but unable to get the desired output. It would be great if you can help me the right command to filter the term and put it in a new field.

[R dplyr filter based on matching search term with first words of any work in select columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52705000/r-dplyr-filter-based-on-matching-search-term-with-first-words-of-any-work-in-sel)

Comment: As the error message is telling you: Your "dataframe" is no dataframe but a matrix. That's why filter is complaining as it is for dataframes. You could try to convert your matrix to a df via. e.g. `as.data.frame`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a new column `component` containing the `type` descriptions to an existing dataframe `df`, which contains the large string given in the post, then this should work:

Solution:

```
df$component <- str_extract_all(df$v1, '(?<=bi:component name="\\w{1,100}" type=")[^"]+')
```

This makes use of positive lookbehind `(?<=...)`as well as the fact that `\\w` does not only match letters but also digits *and* the underscore, which are all involved in the values for `bi:component name`.

Result:

```
df
v1
1 </bi:data_source_alias>\n    <bi:component name="ROOT" type="ABSOLUTE_LAYOUT_COMPONENT">\n        <bi:component name="CHART_1" type="com_sap_ip_bi_VizFrame">\n            <bi:property name="LEFT_MARGIN" value="31"/>`       <bi:property name="TOP_MARGIN" value="64"/>\n<bi:component name="SCORECARD_1" type="com_sap_ip_bi_Scorecard">\n            <bi:property name="LEFT_MARGIN" value="9"/>
                                                                   component
1 ABSOLUTE_LAYOUT_COMPONENT, com_sap_ip_bi_VizFrame, com_sap_ip_bi_Scorecard
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  v1 = '</bi:data_source_alias>
    <bi:component name="ROOT" type="ABSOLUTE_LAYOUT_COMPONENT">
        <bi:component name="CHART_1" type="com_sap_ip_bi_VizFrame">
            <bi:property name="LEFT_MARGIN" value="31"/>`       <bi:property name="TOP_MARGIN" value="64"/>
<bi:component name="SCORECARD_1" type="com_sap_ip_bi_Scorecard">
            <bi:property name="LEFT_MARGIN" value="9"/>'
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris. That really helped. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I was able to get the desired output earlier with the command                       
        df$component <- str_extract_all(df$v1, '(?<=bi:component name="\\w{1,100}" type=")[^"]+') However Now I want to get all the bi

Comment: Sorry that was incomplete.    I was able to get the desired output earlier with the command df$component <- str_extract_all(df$v1, '(?<=bi:component name="\\w{1,100}" type=")[^"]+') However Now I want to get all the text after = in bi:component name and before type that is CHART_1 and SCORECARD_1 in a new column called BI Comp Name and all the text in bi:property name after = and before value that is LEFT_MARGIN in a separate column called BI Property Name. How do I apply two filters on a same dataset and put it in 2 separate columns. I've triedthis separately for each filter but its not wrkng

Comment: df2 <- df %>%
  select(V1) %>%
        filter(str_detect(V1, %like% %"<bi:property name="LEFT_MARGIN"%")) %>% as Property_Type
           count(V1) I am using this command but I am not getting the desired output. This is the error message I am getting Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  select(V1) %>%
        filter(str_detect(V1, "%like% %<bi:property name="vizType"
>            count(V1)
Error in group_vars(x) : object 'V1' not found
>